# How can i update data sessions by SID after headers sended?

Tags: php, session

Sometimes, after user request, is necesary to keep run current script in background to process some events about updates. Specific events must update some keys on user session.
My code:

```
<php 
ini_set('session.save_path',__DIR__ . '/../!PHPSESSID');
session_start();


// ...... page content - db queries and other stuff. here can be generated some events

//close user connection and keep running script in background
ignore_user_abort(true);
//fastcgi_finish_request(); -- no need in my case
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
session_write_close();
ob_end_flush();
flush();

//OK, user connection are closed. This script is running now in bacground
set_time_limit(120); // for me is more than enough - OR set 0

//... my database store all sids by each user id for each connections (e.g. same user, by id 123, have connections: 2 from pc(difrent browser), 1 from mobile .... ). I always know how ~ many connections user have and how to find him to send some events

if($haveSomeSpecificEvents){
    foreach($specificEvents as $item){
        if(!file_exists(session_save_path().'/sess_'.$item['sid'])){
            continue; //skip
        }

        session_id($item['sid']); // generate warning: headers already sent
        session_start(); // generate warning: headers already sent

        //check if session is what i am looking for like $_SESSION['id'] == $item['user_id'], if not - just skip this

        //place some updates (flag) in $_SESSION, but is always NULL.

        session_write_close(); // save changes

    }

 }
```

Of cource, i can do request using **CURL** to my domain - i think this is not a good ideea.

P.S: English is not my first language

Comment: Don't. This is a bad idea. The only thing that should ever touch session data is PHP, and anything outside of that is going to result in missing/corrupted session data. Whatever you're trying to update likely shouldn't live in the session data in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Sam, but i have no choise. As i know, only one connections can be handle same session - here can't be corrupded data. Thats why, i always call **session_write_close**  as soon as possible when script may running longer (bkg part code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I waited for someone to answer my question, but I had to answer it myself. Maybe this will help someone. My solution: turn on output buffering. Just add `ob_start();` on top the script.